# Why is mypy/PyCharm/etc not detecting type errors for Type[T]?

Tags: python, pycharm, mypy, python-typing, typing

Consider the following code:

```
def verify(schema: Type[T], data: T) -> None:
    pass

verify(int, "3")
verify(float, "3")
verify(str, "3")
```

I would expect the first two `verify()` calls to show up as a type error, and the last one to not.

However, none of them show up with type errors, in PyCharm and in mypy. I tried enabling every possible flag for strictness and error codes, yet nothing.

How can I get a type-checker to type-check this? Why does it fail?

Libraries like `apischema` rely on functionality like this for type-checking, e.g., `apischema.serialize(MyDataclass, my_dataclass)`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: why do you expect type error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type bound to `T` is not determined by any single argument; it is chosen in a way that satisfies the call. Since `object` is the closest common supertype of `int`-and-`str` or `float`-and-`str`), `T` is bound to `object` in those cases. (For `verify(str, "3")`, `T` is bound to `str` for the same reason: it's the trivial closest supertype of `str` and `str`).

You can see this by having `verify` return `schema`, then asking `mypy` what the return value has.

```
def verify(schema: Type[T], data: T) -> Type[T]:
    return schema

reveal_type(verify(int, "3"))  # builtins.object
reveal_type(verify(float, "3"))  # builtins.object
reveal_type(verify(str, "3"))  # builtins.str
```

If you can enumerate the types you expect to pass to `schema`, you can partially solve the problem by making `T` a *constrained* type variable.

```
T = TypeVar('T', int, str, float)

def verify(schema: Type[T], data: T) -> None:
    ...
```

Since `T` can no longer be bound to `object`, your first two examples will fail to type-check as desired.

---

Note that something like the following will still pass:

```
class MyFloat(float):
    pass


verify(MyFloat, 3.14)
```

because `T` will be bound to `float`, the closest common superclass of `float` and `MyFloat`. (This isn't really any different from the case with `object`, but tends to "look" less surprising.)

Comment: It may be worth noting that this behavior of `int` + `str` -> `object` is not _necessary_, but a choice made by any given type checker. MyPy chooses to use a **join** on those types as it does in many similar instances (and this behavior is [quite contentious](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12056)) and joining is what you described here. But another way to deal with this would be to use a **union**, i.e. `T` collapsing to `int | str`. I believe Pyright does this, though I have not tested it. I don't know what PyCharm's built-in checker does.

Comment: This is such a well-explained answer, and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Any thoughts on how you might go looking to get the behaviour I intended?

Comment: So if B subclasses A, `Type[{some B object}]` would match `Type[{some A object}]`, and that's why `int` matches `object`.

Comment: Not quite. The type checker examines each call to the function, and based on the static types of the arguments, *chooses* which type to assign to `T`. So given `str` and `1`, `T` is chosen (by `mypy`) to be `object` since `str` is compatible with `Type[object]` and `1` is compatible with `object`.